# How do I get all the dates with a particular time from a zoo object?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

Suppose I have a zoo object of date/times (POSIXct) as my index and values:

```
...                     val
2006-08-01 10:00:00      1
2006-08-01 10:10:00      2
2006-08-01 10:20:00      3
2006-08-01 10:30:00      4
...
2006-08-02 10:00:00      5
2006-08-02 10:10:00      6
2006-08-02 10:20:00      7
2006-08-02 10:30:00      8
...
```

This should be simple but I can't think of how to get a list of all dates/times where let's say the time is 10:10:00am ...

---

**Sample zoo data object:**

```
Lines <- "datetime val
2006-08-01T10:00    1
2006-08-01T10:10    2
2006-08-01T10:20    3
2006-08-01T10:30    4
2006-08-01T10:40    10
2006-08-02T10:10    5
2006-08-02T10:20    6
2006-08-02T10:30    7
2006-08-02T10:40    8"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "", header = TRUE, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
```

NOTE: I would prefer a base-R/zoo implementation but other packages would be interesting to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way is to use `lubridate` to extract time components. This assumes `second()` is equal to 0.

```
library(lubridate)

z[hour(index(z)) == 10 & minute(index(z)) == 10]
```

You can also coerce to character and then search for the specific time.

```
z[grep("10:10:00", index(z))]
```

---

Out of curiosity, I ran a benchmark. The results are presumably due to the type conversion and are obviously insignificant on a small data set.

[image: benchmark]

It slows down as you add more criteria though. If you add in `seconds(index(z)) == 0`, then the `lubridate` method is basically the same. The `grep` solutions are probably the way to go.

```
library(microbenchmark)

benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  lubridate = z[hour(index(z)) == 10 & minute(index(z)) == 10],
  grep = z[grep("10:10:00", index(z))]
)
```

Comment: I would prefer not to parse out the time string but say "give me all rows where the time is 10:10:00"

Comment: Wow, that's nice!

Comment: The lubridate code assumes the seconds in the data is always 0 whereas the grep code does not.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` or `grepl` like this. No additional packages are used.

```
z[grepl("10:10:00", time(z))]
## 2006-08-01 10:10:00 2006-08-02 10:10:00 
##                   2                   6
```

Another approach is to use `substr` or `substring`:

```
z[substring(time(z), 12, 20) == "10:10:00"])
## 2006-08-01 10:10:00 2006-08-02 10:10:00 
##                   2                   6
```

If we knew the positions then another possibility is to use them:

```
z[seq(2, length(z), 4)]
## 2006-08-01 10:10:00 2006-08-02 10:10:00 
##                   2                   6
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form was assumed to be the following. (It seems that the code below was copied to the question.)

```
Lines <- "datetime        val
2006-08-01T10:00:00      1
2006-08-01T10:10:00      2
2006-08-01T10:20:00      3
2006-08-01T10:30:00      4
2006-08-02T10:00:00      5
2006-08-02T10:10:00      6
2006-08-02T10:20:00      7
2006-08-02T10:30:00      8"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, tz = "", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base::strftime`:

```r
z[strftime(z, format="%H:%M:%S") == strftime("1000-01-01 10:10:00", format="%H:%M:%S")]

 #> 2006-08-01 10:10:00 2006-08-02 10:10:00 
 #>                   2                   5
```